# Marshal a float matrix array in C# struct

Tags: c#, data-structures, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

Defined in a pagefile I'm reading out there is a float matrix, in the c++ header it is defined like this

```
// other properties above
float value[60][3];
// other properties below
```

Up until this point I have mapped everything sequentially in a struct and it reads out the values correctly. However, with this float matrix I am stuck.
I tried experimenting and did the thing below, but of course it doesn't work that way...

```
// other properties above
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 60*3)]
public float[][] value;
// other properties below
```

Does anyone know how I can properly put this in a sequential struct layout?

Thanks,
Y

Comment: Have you tried a twodimensional array instead of a nested array? `float[,]`

Comment: Or a plain linear array. The marshaller is good, but it doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that linear array may be the best compromise here

Comment: linear array, how would I go about that then in calculating the size? Same as I tired.
I will try both approaches, the twodimensional and the nested one... Fact is I don't need that readout, but I need to map it so I can read the properties below correctly. Is there a way to skip a given amount of bytes when doing a sequential layout?

Comment: @SomeBody make an answer out of it, it actually worked!
`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 60 * 3)]
public float[,] value;`
That made the difference. I could of course get rid of 60*3 and put in 180, but I prefer the first for readibility.

Comment: That can't be right for reading, the pinvoke marshaler won't know the size of the dimensions.  Beyond a linear array, indexed with 3*y + x, it is likely that a struct with 3 float members produces much more readable code.

Comment: @HansPassant I got it working with the 2dimensional array, see above. But do explain your concept of defining another struct, for readability sake I would like to include it, if needed in future use indeed... But I'm quite new in this, so an answer or example could be beneficial. Thanks.

Comment: The low dimension of the array has 3 float values.  Surely you can give them a good name.

Comment: ps: by "got it working" I meant, the bytes are being read, but I don't know the values, so @HansPassant you are right, I probably can't use the values now like this, I just skip them so I can read out the properties that come after it.

Comment: sure @HansPassant - but would it be like three floats each with sizconst of 60? as in 
`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 60)]
        public float[] values1; [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 60)]
        public float[] values2; [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 60)]
        public float[] values3;`
 ---- just asking because IDK what you mean otherwise? Regardless of the naming of properties ;-)

PS: doesn't anyone use this "answer" option here anymore LOL...

Comment: Make a struct with three floats in it. Then declare an array of that struct, with length 60